# Deploy Sinatra project

Tags: ruby, deployment, backend, sinatra-activerecord

I have just started learning ruby. So now I have setup a basic Sinatra project, just wondering where I can deploy it for free without credit card details? As Heroku has no free tier anymore. Also, I would like to know with the seeds.rb I generate random data, would those data be able to used after deploy.

I have tried couple other platforms(render, railway, AWS…), but they either are not free or hard for deploying

Answer (score 0):

Currently Fly.io and Digital Ocean are popular replacement for Heroku.

Yes, you can seed the database used in the deployment.

Then you can either

1. Run `rake db:seed` on the deployed application or
2. Connect to the database from you development machine and run `rake db:seed`